# R Heat Map , Labels on Y axis coming out to be very close

Tags: r, heatmap

I  am using R to plot the heat map of a data in CSV file (10 (Columns) Conditions and 1000 (Rowa))

Following is the Code I am using ..

```
nba <- read.csv("1317754115.csv", sep=",")
nba_matrix <- data.matrix(nba)
cexRow = 0.2 + 1/log10(1000),
cexCol = 0.2 + 1/log10(10),
nba_heatmap <- heatmap(nba_matrix, Rowv=cexRow, Colv=cexCol, 
    col = heat.colors(256), scale="column", margins=c(5,10))
```

[image]
[Heat Map Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmATL.png)

Now Rows on right hand sides are  very close so I can not read the label names ,

Can some one please tell me how can i show all labels on Y-Axis

Thanks

Comment: don't forget to add the image you are currently getting from your plot

Comment: Sorry , I missed the Image , I have added the link for the heatmap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the aspect ratio with the base `heatmap` function. To get this functionality, see `heatmap.2` in the `gplots` package, or `aspectHeatmap` in the `ClassDiscovery` package. Here's an example:

```
require(gplots)

nrow = 100
ncol = 10

set.seed(12345)
row.names = replicate(nrow, paste(letters[sample(10)], collapse=''))
col.names = replicate(ncol, paste(letters[sample(10)], collapse=''))

values = matrix(runif(nrow*ncol), nrow=nrow, dimnames=list(row.names, col.names))

dev.new(width=5, height=10)
heatmap(values)
dev.new(width=5, height=10)
heatmap.2(values)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you John , My Heat Map looks much better now